# variable length bit packing in C

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am trying to write c functions ReadInt32, WriteInt32 for packing bits sequentially in a stream buffer with size optimisation in mind.
But my functions do not work as expected, I don't find the same values back after writing them in the buffer. I need a little bit of help to point what and where I have misunderstood.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BITSET(x,n)    (x | ( 1 << n))
#define BITCLEAR(x,n)  (x & ~(1 << n))
#define ISBITSET(x,n)  ((x & (1 << n)) != 0)

/**
 @param nbits The number of bits to write
 @param val the integer value to write
 @param bufptr a pointer on the buffer to write in
 @param nbitswritten the number of bits already written in the previous write.
 @return the number of bits actually written.
*/
int WriteInt32(int nbits, int val, uint8_t* bufptr, int nbitswritten)
{
   uint8_t* p=(uint8_t*)&val;
   uint8_t* ptr = &(*(bufptr+nbitswritten));

   for (int i=0; i<nbits; i++)
   {
       int bpos = (i&0x7);
       *(ptr+(i>>3)) = ISBITSET(*(p+(i>>3)), bpos) ? (BITSET(*(ptr+(i>>3)), bpos)) : (BITCLEAR(*(ptr+(i>>3)), bpos));

   }
   return (nbitswritten + nbits);
}

int ReadInt32(int nbits, int& val, uint8_t* ptr, int nbitsread)
{
    val = 0;
    uint8_t* p = &(*(ptr+nbitsread));
    for (int i=0; i<nbits; i++)
    {
        uint8_t ch = *(p+(i>>3));
        int bpos = (i&0x7);
        val = (ISBITSET(ch, bpos) ? BITSET(val, bpos) : BITCLEAR(val, bpos));
    }
    return (nbitsread+nbits);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int value = 289;     // for example I want to encode this value on 10 bits
    unsigned char buf[50];

    // packing
    int nbitswritten = 0;
    nbitswritten = WriteInt32 (10, value, buf, 50, nbitswritten);

    // unpacking - read from buffer
    int nbitsread = 0;
    int rvalue;
    nbitsread = ReadInt32(10, rvalue, buf, nbitsread);

    if ( value == rvalue)
        printf("encoding & decoding ok\n");
    else
        printf("encoding or decoding failed\n");

   return 0;
};
```

Thank you
Olivier

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: "Obviously It does not work." means ??   What are the errors(if any)?, whats the expected output?

Comment: This doesn't currently compile due to `bzero(buf);`, which should be `bzero(buf,50);`.  Even if that is fixed, the program doesn't attempt to output anything, so how would you know if it's working?

Comment: Ok I understand you. After packing then unpacking the data, I should find again the same values.  objId = robjId, state = mistake, flag = myflag, etc. This is not the case.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement(s) are causing the issue?  What are the values in the variables for that statement?

Comment: Your `WriteInt32` function lies.  If nothing happens, it returns the passed variable, which is a lie; it should return 0 if zero bytes are written.

Comment: Save yourself some energy and use `std::bitset`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. My function lies and I should use std::bitset. So, show me the trick and small guys like me could learn something.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to my own question. How to write/read an integer encoded in smaller size than its natural size.
If it can help someone. That's good. ;)

exemple:

```
struct dd
{  
    short   var1:5;   // This variable is encoded on 5 bits
    int     var2:11;  // This variable is encoded on 11 bits
    uint8_t var3:3;   // This variable is encoded on 3 bits 
};

uint8_t buffer[100];
bzero(buffer, 100);
int nbitswritten = 0;
struct dd vardd = { 16, 452, 3 };

// write stuff
nbitswritten = WriteBits(5, vardd.var1, buffer, 100, nbitswritten);
nbitswritten = WriteBits(11, vardd.var2, buffer, 100, nbitswritten);
nbitswritten = WriteBits(3, vardd.var3, buffer, 100, nbitswritten);

// read back
int v1, v2, v3;
int nbitsread = 0;
struct dd result;
nbitsread = ReadInt(5, v1, buffer, 100, nbitsread);
nbitsread = ReadInt(11, v2, buffer, 100, nbitsread);
nbitsread = ReadInt(3, v3, buffer, 100, nbitsread);

result.var1 = (short)v1;
result.var2 = v2;
result.var3 = (uint8_t)v3;
```

Actually the Read functions comes from the Torque Engine library!!
This is my slightly modified version :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BITSET(x,n)    (x | ( 1 << n))
#define BITCLEAR(x,n)  (x & ~(1 << n))
#define ISBITSET(x,n)  ((x & (1 << n)) != 0)

/**
 @param nbits The number of bits to write
 @param val the value to write
 @param bufptr the buffer to write to/in
 @param buflen the maximum buffer length in byte/octet
 @param nbitswritten the number of bits in bufptr already written.
 @return the number of bits written;
*/
int WriteBits(int nbits, const void * val, uint8_t * bufptr, int buflen, int nbitswritten)
{
    if (!bufptr || !val || !nbits || !buflen)
       return 0;

    if ( nbitswritten >= buflen<<8L )
       return 0;

    if ( nbits+nbitswritten>buflen<<8L )
       return 0;

    uint8_t* p=(uint8_t*)val;
    int n = nbitswritten;
    for (int i=0; i<nbits; i++)
    {
       int sbpos = (i&0x7);
       int dbpos = (n&0x7);
       *(bufptr+(n>>3)) = ISBITSET(*(p+(i>>3)), sbpos) ? (BITSET(*(bufptr+(n>>3)), dbpos)) : (BITCLEAR(*(bufptr+(n>>3)), dbpos));
       n++;
    }
    nbitswritten = n;
    return (n);
}

int ReadBits(int nbits, void * val, uint8_t * bufptr, int buflen, int nbitsread)
{
    if (!nbits)
        return 0;

    uint8_t * stPtr = (bufptr + (nbitsread >> 3));
    int byteCount = (nbits + 7) >> 3;

    uint8_t * ptr = (TUint8*)val;

    int downShift = nbitsread & 0x7;
    int upShift = 8 - downShift;

    uint8_t curB = *stPtr;
    const uint8_t *stEnd = bufptr + buflen;
    while(byteCount--)
    {
       stPtr++;
       uint8_t nextB = stPtr < stEnd ? *stPtr : 0;
       *ptr++ = (curB >> downShift) | (nextB << upShift);
       curB = nextB;
    }

    nbitsread += nbits;
    return nbitsread;
}

int ReadInt(int nbits, int &val, uint8_t * bufptr, int buflen, int nbitsread)
{
    int ret = ReadBits(nbits, &val, bufptr, buflen, nbitsread);
    if (nbits != 32) {
       val &= (1<<nbits)-1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Olive